# Login to App using Json Data iOS

Tags: ios, json, wcf, authentication

Another question about parsing Json Data.

Previously I used a NsDictionary to store my users so that they could log into my app, This isn't really ideal since I have to release an update to add a new user so Im looking to create a method to parse out the Json data to see if there is a user that matches on the server. I have already created the WCF and it is returning data like so..

```
{
"RetrieveUsersResult": [
    {
       "Active": true,
       "Email": "email@email.co.uk",
       "ID": 2,
       "Password": "password",
       "UserName": "user1 "
    },
   {
       "Active": false,
       "Email": "email@email.com",
       "ID": 3,
       "Password": "password2",
       "UserName": "user2 "
    }]                
}
```

So that is returning me a list of users.  I have created a method to retrieve the data and store it to an array.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)parseJSONUsers{

    NSString *urlAsString = @"webaddress";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {

             NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

             NSMutableArray *retrieveUsersResultArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"RetrieveLocationsResult"]];

             //Need to do something with retrieveUsersResultArr Here



         } else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }

     }];

    return retval;

    [retval release];
    [urlRequest release];
    [url release];
    [urlAsString release];

}
```

Could you help me check to see if there is a user in the retrieveUsersResultArr that matches the username text field and the password text field.

Comment: Just a comment, but why would you save the password plain text and set you full list of user to the app. With a simple man in the middle attack I could not grab all your user and there password. Even if they are in the app (NSDictionary) they should not be plaintext. The best way is to authenticate a user serverside, set an encrypted password to the server er verify the account on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to send the username and password to the WCF web service and perform the authentication on the server-side. Hash the password in the app before you send it. Better yet, send the credentials to the server over HTTPS.

The way you're doing it now, you risk exposing every single user's email address and password to just about anyone who discovers your unsecured web service.

Comment: So, instead I will create my stored procedure so as I need to send a username and password to the WCF and if I get a return of that user I will let them through?

Comment: Yes, use the data sent to the server to compare the username and hashed passwords (don't store passwords as plain text in your database) and return the matching record for that user. Scrub the data being returned via WCF to _not_ include the stored password.

Comment: I see, so how would I go about posting the data to the WCF? I will post the two fields and if it returns with a username then it will authenticate the user.

Comment: Search Google for "HTTP POST NSURLConnection iOS". There's 100s of examples.